# SqlException Connection.Open() in Device Application

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-ce

I have this code for my price checker device running on Windows CE

But I get a `SqlException` on the line

```
cmd.Connection.Open();
```

Is the problem in the connection string or in another part of my code?

```
constring = "Password=12345;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=Retail;Data Source=111.111.111.111";

private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < textBox1.Text.Length; i++)
        {
            if (char.IsDigit(textBox1.Text, 0) == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Barcode");
                textBox1.Focus();
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    Sql = "Select i.a_name,u.retailprice From sys_item i,sys_item_units u where i.itemean =u.itemean and u.barcode='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
                    cmd = new SqlCommand(Sql, new SqlConnection(constring));
                    da = new SqlDataAdapter(Sql, constring);
                    cmd.Connection.Open();

                    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        label1.Text = dr[0].ToString();
                        label2.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                    }

                    cmd.Connection.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    textBox1.Text = "";
                    textBox1.Focus();
                }
            }
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

the Exception :

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: SqlException at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError() at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError() at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect() at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OpenAndLogin() at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection..ctor() at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at DeviceApplication1.Form1.textBox1_KeyPress() at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnKeyPress() at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WnProc()

Comment: What is the exception content? Please post it here.

Comment: If that's the IP address you're using, I'd assume the connection is failing. You can always log the full exception to a text file and email it to yourself.

Comment: Can you post full exception message?

Comment: Is it on a remote machine? Please check if you are able to connect to SQL instance remotely. Pinging would work if it is in the same network.

Comment: Post the exception in your _question_, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks All For Replies . It's in Firewall of the Server